# can you import your own package in Python?

Tags: python, import, module, package, suds

I'm trying to understand the import-logic in Python.

If you take [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) tutorial as a reference, I think you won't be able to, for example state:

```
from sound.effects import echo
```

At least, not from within the package.

However, Suds (a package I'm interested in) does something like that [here](https://bitbucket.org/mirror/suds/src/1e48fd79a1fc323006826439e469ba7b3d2b5a68/suds/builder.py?at=default)

A fragment of suds/suds/builder.py:

```
from logging import getLogger
from suds import * 
from suds.sudsobject import Factory
..
```

folder structure:

```
suds/
    ...no_package_init_file_here...
    suds/
        __init__.py
        builder.py
        sudsobject.py
        ...
```

How, and why does this work?

I thought it was kind-of 'not-allowed' to use the container package name within the package. As a rule of thumb.

Now, there is one thing I can think of: suds will add itself to the PYTHONPATH and thereby becomes accessible to every level. Is that the reason?

And, do you guys think that Suds has a smart solution here? Or is a bit hacky?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

both solutions are supported. from within a package you can use:

```
from mypackage import mymodule
```

or

```
import mymodule
```

and if you just want to import a single class from a module

```
from mypackage import mymodule.myclass
```

or

```
import mymodule.myclass
```

Comment: can you show your folder structure and the python file that is calling it? I think it's all relative.

Comment: I think it will return a `ImportError: No module named mypackage` if this was called from mypackage/mytest.py.

Comment: why don't you test it instead of saying 'I think it will...'

Comment: I tested it, and in fact I get the ImportError mentioned before. However, I think it depends on the package structure you have in mind. I think it only works when the calling script is next to (thus outside) 'mypackage'. It gives an error when in the package (e.g. mypackage/mytest.py)

Comment: That's not correct. It works perfectly fine from within that package. say mypackage contains mytest.py and mytest2.py, you can import mypackage.mytest from inside of mytest2

Comment: as long as mypackage contains a `__init__.py`

Comment: OK, doing the following: `cd mypackage; python mytest.py` Is that different than what you are doing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33225/discussion-between-paul-r-and-hsmit)

Answer (score 0):

**sounds like pythonpath..**

After studying this a bit, I found out it all depends on the PYTHONPATH or `sys.path`.
So, `from sound.effects import echo` works from within the `sound` package (first example) when `sound` is found in `sys.path`.
And that only happens if `sound` is located in a directory that exists in `sys.path`.

**relative to executed script**

When the executed script (.py file or interpreter) is called from a directory where the sound package can be found, not errors are raised. This is because that directory is the first element in the `sys.path` list.
But, when the executed script is inside the package itself, it won't find `sound` and therefore a `ImportError: No module named sound` will be raised. Unless of course, `sound` is included at another level of `sys.path` (for example in `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`).

**about suds**

Now, for `suds` this import statement was correct. And that is because the `suds` package exists in the PYTHONPATH (`sys.path`). In that way, the `from suds.sudsobject import Factory` calls the version of suds in PYTHONPATH (dist-packages).

*extra*:

In my case, I wanted to modify `suds` source code and therefore I placed a copy of the entire dir in my lib: `my_package/lib/suds/`. The calling script (.py) could however not find `suds` because it was 1 level too deep. And then import errors were raised because suds could not be loaded properly

When you don't want `suds` in/from the `dist-packages` you can add it to `sys.path` manually:

```
import sys, os
suds_parent = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib')
if suds_parent not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(suds_parent)
```